# Can't access the variable inside the generated code from pyqt5

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

this is my first post and I would like to thanks the amazing community of Stack Overflow for helping me during all this years!

However, after extensive research, i couldn't find a solution to my problem. I have the file generated by QtCreator which contain a progressbar.
In my code, I have 2 class, and 1 is a Thread. This Thread must change the value of the progressbar, but I completely fail to do so.

I can't access the variable from my Thread, but i can from the init of Mainwindow. I think the problem is the nature of the "self" variable in setprogressBar, but I'm literally stuck finding out what it is..

When i tried to execute this code, here is the result :

```
File "C:\test.py", line 14, in setprogressBar
self.progressBar.setProperty("value", pourcentage)
AttributeError: type object 'MainWindow' has no attribute 'progressBar'
```

File A, generated with QtCreator :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.widget)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
```

File B, my code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from UImainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from threading import Thread
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
 # access variables inside of the UI's file
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) # gets defined in the UI file
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24) #This is working

    def setprogressBar(self, pourcentage):
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", pourcentage) #This is not

class B(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):          
        MainWindow.setprogressBar(MainWindow ,48)

APP = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

Bi = B()
Bi.start()

MAINWIN = MainWindow()
MAINWIN.show()

APP.exec_()
```

Thx a lot for the help guys !

Comment: You can only call Qt methods from the main thread. You cannot call them from B.run. You have to arrange to marshell a call from B.run back into your main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainWindow` is a class, not an object. What you should do instead is something like:

```
class B(Thread):
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.__target = target

    def run(self):
        self.__target.setprogressBar(48)

MAINWIN = MainWindow()

bi = B(MAINWIN)
bi.start()

MAINWIN.show()
```